# join together about 60 time series csv files

Tags: python, csv, glob

I have some code that downloads monthly data for each month since about 2006, so a fair amount of files. 
Then I run some other code that joins all the monthly files into one big file containing all the data(note after the first file, it removes the heading each time after):

```
from glob import glob
files = sorted(glob('*.csv'))

with open('VIC.csv', 'w') as fi_out:
    for i, fname_in in enumerate(files):            
        with open(fname_in, 'r') as fi_in:               
            for i_line, line in enumerate(fi_in):
                 (i_line > 0)
                if i_line > 0 or i == 0:
                    fi_out.write(line)
```

This works well except now I want to do the same but for different states.
I.e. before my downloaded files looked like this:

[image: before]

Now looks like this:

[image: now]

So when I run my code, it stuffs up.

Ideally I would like it to make two csv files, one called VIC with all the VIC data joined and one called QLD with all the QLD data joined. However I am not sure how to modify my code to do this?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, at the botom is the code I adapted. First I took the code you had, and refactored it in a function called `merge`. This function, you call with with the `inputFiles` and the `outputFileName`. In your first case, you call this with:

`merge(sorted(glob('*.csv')), 'VIC.csv')`

Now you have 2 sets of data. Instead of calling it on all .csv input files, we call it only on the VIC.csv input files:

`merge(sorted(glob('*VIC1.csv')), 'VIC.csv')`

And this we repeat then for the QLD files as well. The full code is shown below.

Kind regards

```
from glob import glob

def merge(inputFiles, outputFileName):
    with open(outputFileName, 'w') as fi_out:
        for i, fname_in in enumerate(inputFiles):            
            with open(fname_in, 'r') as fi_in:               
                for i_line, line in enumerate(fi_in):
                    (i_line > 0)
                    if i_line > 0 or i == 0:
                        fi_out.write(line)

merge(sorted(glob('*VIC1.csv')), 'VIC.csv')
merge(sorted(glob('*QLD1.csv')), 'QLD.csv')
```

---

A minor refactor that doesn't need to keep track of which file or line is being processed.

```
def merge(inputFiles, outputFileName):
    inputFiles = iter(inputFiles)
    with open(outputFileName, 'w') as fi_out:
        #process the first file
        with open(next(inputFiles)) as first_file:
            fi_out = firstfile.read()
        #now just skip the first line in the other files
        for fname in inputFiles:            
            with open(fname_in, 'r') as fi_in:
                skip = next(f_in)
                fi_out.write(fi_in.read())
```

Comment: Works perfect thanks so much! Thanks for explaining what you did as well, helps a lot learning